# Views: Filter and/or sort by computed field - hook_views_data()

Tags: views

I have created a computed field, using ComputedFieldTrait. It is working fine, I am able to add the computed on the manage layout pages. I have implemented hook_views_data_alter() to tell Views about the computed field, and I am able to add the computed field to a view.

However, I need to do both a sort and a filter on the computed field.

My question: How do I structure my return value from hook_views_data_alter() so that views can use my computed field for sorting and filtering? Or is this even possible?

Comment: I think this was asked before and turned out to be not possible as the sorting happens in the DB query.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's possible. Hoping it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort View on rewritten field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298581/how-to-sort-view-on-rewritten-field)

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/140877/15055

Comment: It turns out it's not possible. I came up with a workaround by creating custom views filter and sort plugins, that altered a column value in the query in the same manner I was altering the field value in the computed field. It works for my situation. But the answer to this question is that views cannot sort or filter on computed fields.

Comment: Sounds like a proper answer, though. Would you mind adding an outline of the views filter and sort plugins as answer?